# Parallel.ForEach and global variable

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel.foreach, plinq

If I have code as following:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, NetObject>();
Parallel.ForEach(results, options, result =>                    
{
    var items = parser.Parse(result);
    Parallel.ForEach(items, options, nextObject =>                      
    {
        if (nextObject != null)
        {
            dict[nextObject.Id] = nextObject;
        }
    });
});
```

The dict is a dictionary defined at method level. My question is, will it cause parallel foreach to work like normal foreach in synchronous manner since it is global object? I do not see any performance difference between normal foreach and parallel once for the code above.

Comment: dictionary is not thread safe by the way

Comment: What type of dictionary is it? Regarding the synchronization: that's a matter of how it was implemented by Microsoft, not where in memory it is

Comment: is the method async?

Comment: Use `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: you don't know what kind of Dictionary it is, yet. Maybe a ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @McNultyyy: will that have any benefits if you have write accesses only?

Comment: @ChitKhine It is simple dictionary. Initialized like new Dictionary<string, NetObject>();

Comment: @McNultyyy I will try with ConcurrentDictionary now and update here if something works fast!

Comment: @ChitKhine Method is not async.

Comment: I'm assuming you already know that this ought to be quicker in Parallel, but even if so, the bottom paragraph here could be useful (sometimes LINQ decides to execute in sequential mode if it thinks it will be just as fast) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd997399(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: how many iterations do you expect? try input that would generate tens of thousands iterations at least

Comment: @slawekwin I have some 8000 records right now. Both parallel and single thread foreach gives same performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe. You're mutating a `Dictionary<K, V>` which isn't a thread-safe data structure. Also, you're most likely over parallelising the loop with both `Parallel.ForEach` to iterate the inner and outter loop.

Let me suggest a different approach using [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx), which doesn't require you to synchronize a global `Dictionary`. Note you should make sure there are no duplicate keys when doing this (perhaps with an additional `.Distinct()` call):

```
results
  .AsParallel()
  .SelectMany(x => parser.Parse(x))
  .Where(x => x != null)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
```

But of course, the most important thing is to benchmark your code to make sure that parallelism is actually increasing performance, and that you're gaining anything from this.

Comment: Thanks Yuval. Let me try this out.